# Real-space correlations of massless Majorana fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, majorana-fermions

Consider an action of free, massless Majorana fermions in real time and 1+1 dimensions of the form
$$
S[\psi] = \frac{1}{2} \int d^2x \ \psi^{T}\gamma^0 (i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}) \psi
$$
Here, $\psi$ is a two-component spinor. I would like to compute real space correlations of the field $\psi$. I've already done this problem in imaginary time, where the result is relatively simple and can be checked in many CFT books. I'm trying to check my understanding by doing it in real time as well, but I'm running into some issues.

For simplicity, I'll work in the chiral basis: set $\gamma^0 = \sigma^x$ and $\gamma^1 = -i\sigma^y$, so that the action reads (with $\psi = (\psi_+, \psi_-)^T$)
$$
S = \frac{1}{2} \int d^2 x \ \left\{ \psi_+ (i \partial_t + i \partial_x) \psi_+ + \psi_-(i \partial_t - i \partial_x) \psi_- \right\}
$$
From the action, I would guess that the correlator for $\psi_+$ is given by
$$
\langle \psi_+(t,x) \psi_+(0) \rangle = \int \frac{dp d\omega}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{i}{\omega-p+i\varepsilon} e^{ipx-i\omega t}
$$
However, this correlation function seems quite problematic to me, for a few reasons. For example, suppose I evaluate the $\omega$ integral first. Then I find that the propagator is *zero* for $t<0$, since the contour must be closed in the upper half plane. Similarly, the correlator is zero for $x<0$. How can these be? I would have thought that since $\psi_+$ is a Grassmann field inside the path integral,
$$
\langle \psi_+(t,x) \psi_+(t',x') \rangle = -\langle \psi_+(t',x') \psi_+(t,x) \rangle
$$
But this is clearly inconsistent with the above.

My suspicion is that this has something to do with an incorrect use of the $i\varepsilon$ prescription, since the $+i\varepsilon$ in the denominator seems to be the issue for all three problems. But I'm not sure how to handle these issues. In the bosonic case typically one might argue that the $i\varepsilon$ must be added to the action to aid in convergence, which is at least a nice mnemonic. But in the Grassmann case there should be no issue with unbounded Gaussian integrals.

So, here's my question: is my expression for the $\psi_+$ correlator correct? If so, what is wrong with my sanity checks following the expression? And if not, how should it be corrected?

Comment: It is all about the $i\epsilon$ prescription. Choosing different prescriptions (e.g. $\pm i\epsilon$ or $i\epsilon \mathrm{sgn}(\omega)$) gives retarded/advanced/time-ordered correlation functions, and none of them has the naive anti-symmetry in your sanity check since certain ordering of time has been put in place. You might want to consider the correlation function of the theory in Euclidean spacetime, or imaginary time, where the result indeed passes the sanity check.

Comment: I agree with your analysis of the different $i\varepsilon$ prescriptions, but then how should I interpret this theory in real time? Does the theory somehow not make sense in real time? I would have naively thought that I could compute the large distance correlation functions of (say) a transverse field Ising model using a theory like this. (I think I understand the correlations well in Euclidean spacetime, the question is how to make sense of the theory in real time as a check on my comprehension.)

Comment: why would you assume that $\langle \psi_+(t, x)\psi_+(t', x')\rangle = -\langle \psi_+(t', x')\psi_+(t, x)\rangle$? the anti-commutation relations do not hold when the operators are evolved at different times, on? Also, note that as @MengCheng mentioned, the GF you calculated is the retarded GF, which is $\theta(t)\langle \{\psi_+(t, x), \psi_{0, 0}\}\rangle$. The fact that restricting the sign of $t$ restricts the sign of $x$ is because of the chirality of the Majorana fermions (the $+$ are only right moving)

Comment: The theory is completely well-defined in real time, but propagators have poles, so you need to be careful about how you define the correlation function. And it is a feature rather than a bug -- the $i\epsilon$ prescription is how you encode causality in the theory.

Comment: @yyy Expectation values in path integrals *should* always be time-ordered expectation values, which do indeed satisfy $\langle \psi_+(t,x) \psi_+(t',x') \rangle = - \langle \psi_+(t',x') \psi_+(t,x) \rangle$. This is manifest in the construction of the path integral. My impression is that if I'm somehow getting a different correlation function such as the retarded correlation function, then I'm doing something wrong in my evaluation of the path integral.

Comment: @MengCheng Now that I think about it, are you certain that the $i \epsilon \text{sgn}(\omega)$ does not satisfy the antisymmetry? If I replace $t$ and $x$ by $-t$ and $-x$, I can compensate by the change of variables $\omega \to -\omega$ and $p \to -p$, which flips the sign of $\text{sgn}(\omega)$ as well.

Comment: @Zack Yeah, you are probably right. I was sloppy about $i\epsilon \mathrm{sgn}(\omega)$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the answer to my own question. As discussed in the comments, the issue can be traced back to the $i\varepsilon$ prescription -- in my question, the $i\varepsilon$ prescription assumed essentially imposes a retarded response function. But as I stated, the path integral *should* give time-ordered correlation functions. So, how do I see what the correct $i\varepsilon$ prescription is?

To make the answer more transparent, it's worth noting that the same issue as in the Majorana action above occurs in a much more familiar setting as well. Consider the path integral for nonrelativistic free fermions:
$$
\hat{H} = \sum_{k} \xi_k c^{\dagger}_k c_k, \quad S[\bar{c},c] = \int dt \sum_k \bar{c}_k[i \hbar \partial_t - \xi_k]c_k
$$
Clearly, the same problem as before arises here: evaluating the correlation function $\langle Tc_k(t) c^{\dagger}_{k}(t') \rangle$ using the path integral also requires picking an $i\varepsilon$ prescription, and picking the naive $+i\varepsilon$ in the denominator gives the wrong answer.

The solution is to remember that correlation functions in the ground state are actually defined in real time by
$$
\langle c_k(t) \bar{c}_{k}(t') \rangle = \lim_{T \to \infty(1-i\varepsilon)} \frac{1}{Z} \int D[\bar{c},c] \ c_k(t) \bar{c}_k(t') \ \exp \left\{ \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{-T}^T dt \sum_k \bar{c}_k[i \hbar \partial_t - \xi_k]c_k \right\}
$$
where $Z$ is the same expression without $c_k(t) \bar{c}_{k}(t')$. In other words, you have to take $t$ to lie along a slightly imaginary direction to project onto the ground state. With this in mind, the action should really be written
$$
S[\bar{c},c] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \ (1-i\varepsilon) \sum_k \bar{c}_k [i \hbar (1+i\varepsilon) \partial_t - \xi_k] c_k
$$
With this in mind, the correlation function is really
$$
G(k,\omega) = \frac{1}{\hbar \omega -\xi_k(1-i\varepsilon)} = \frac{1}{\hbar \omega - \xi_k + i \varepsilon \text{sgn}(\xi_k)}
$$
which is the correct answer for the ground state momentum-frequency space Green's function.

So, back to my initial question: with the $T \rightarrow \infty (1-i\varepsilon)$ prescription in mind, the correct Green's function is
$$
\langle \psi_+(t,x) \psi_+(0,0) \rangle = \int \frac{dpd\omega}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{i}{\omega - p + i \varepsilon \text{sgn}(p)} e^{ipx-i\omega t}
$$